# iOS RunLoop and DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, nsrunloop, dispatch-queue

Why does the `print("2")` part never get called in the following code?
I'd think that the inner `main.async` would push the block into the main loop's queue,
and then `RunLoop.run` would execute it, but apparently that isn't what happens.
(It prints `1`, `run`, `run`, `run`, etc.)

Also, if I remove the outer `main.async`, and just directly run the code in that block
(still on the main queue, in `viewDidLoad` of a new single-view app),
then the inner `main.async` block does get executed (prints `1`, `run`, `2`).
Why does this change make such a difference?

```
var x = -1
DispatchQueue.main.async {   //  comment out this line for question #2
    print("1")
    x = 1
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("2")
        x = 2
    }
    while x == 1 {
        print("run")
        RunLoop.main.run(mode: .default, before: Date() + 1)
    }
}   //  comment out this line for question #2
```

Comment: FWIW, that kludgy technique of spinning on a run loop is a bit of an anachronism. We don’t see it very often nowadays. It was generally used when someone tried to make an inherently asynchronous process behave synchronously, and used this run loop technique to at least let the run loop to process events. But as you’ve discovered, it isn’t ideal and can introduce these sorts of issues. Plus, there are generally better, more efficient solutions (e.g., embrace asynchronous patterns rather than fighting them).

Comment: @Rob I know, I know. The use case where I'm trying to do something similar is basically a debug tool that kind of replaces normally sync calls with networked RPC calls, and ideally it would be nice if I could use it without having to modify the caller.

Comment: OK. But I had to say it, for the sake of future readers at the very least. Too many new devs unfamiliar with async patterns tend to latch onto these sorts of work-arounds. No offense intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, the first `async` blocks the `main` serial queue until it returns from that outer `async` call, something that won’t happen while `x` is `1`. That inner GCD `async` task (that updates `x` to `2`) will never have a chance to run since that serial GCD queue is now blocked in that `while` loop. The attempt to `run` on the main run loop does not circumvent the rules/behavior of GCD serial queues. It only drains the run loop of events that have been added to it.

In your second example, you haven’t blocked the GCD `main` queue, so when you hit `run`, the dispatched block that updates `x` to `2` does have a chance to run, letting it proceed.

Bottom line, don’t conflate the GCD main queue and the main run loop. Yes, they both use the main thread, but run loops can’t be used to circumvent the behavior of serial GCD queues.